# Writing function without range() method

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop

Hello guys ı'm trying to write function that print out [5,6,8,9,10,11,12] and [5,8,11] but ı can't it just print out [5,12]

I tried different ways and also do some researches but ı can't print out without range() method.How can ı print without using range() method?

```
def asc_range(start,end,increment = 1):
i = start
for i in [start,end]:
    yield i 
    i += increment 
print list(asc_range(5,12))
```

Comment: Any particular reason you want to skip 7?

Comment: No actually ı'm learning python but ı stuck there then ı want to ask how this thing works

Comment: print ([i for i in range(5,13) if i != 7])

Comment: ı knew this way @ncica but ı can not use range() method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for loop is used for iterating over a sequence,and in this case you have list [5,12]

its printing just 5 and 12 because you have:

```
for i in [start,end]: # for i in [5,12]:
```

where in first iteration i will be 5,and in second iteration i will be 12.

you should do it like:

```
def asc_range(start,end,increment = 1):
    i = start
    while i <= end:
        if i != 7:
            yield i
        i += increment
print (list(asc_range(5,12)))
```

edit:

you can do something like this, but it doesnt have any sence do do it on this way:

```
ar=[]

def asc_range(start,end):
    for i in [start]:
        if i == end:
            ar.append(end)
            return ar
        else:
            if i != 7:
                ar.append(i)
            return asc_range(i + 1, end)

print (list(asc_range(5,12)))
```